# Referencing a controller class attribute in the FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've got a JavaFX application with an FXML file and a designated Java class to act as a controller for that FXML.  How would I bind a class attribute to a value in the FXML?  For example:

My controller class:

```
    public class MyController{
    ...
    @FXML
    static String myString = "this is text";
    ...
}
```

And the following FXML:

```
<Pane fx:controller="MyController">
    ...
    <String fx:value="MyController.myString">
    ...
</Pane>
```

If I did the above, the `fx:value` would bind to the literal `"MyController.myString"`.  How do I bind it to the static variable I set in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<MyController fx:constant="myString"/>
```

(assuming you have the appropriate import for your controller class in the FXML file). I haven't tested, but you probably need to make `myString` final.

---

If you want to bind to something variable, i.e. not a constant, you can define a property in the FXML itself:

```xml
<fx:define>
    <SimpleStringProperty fx:id="myString" />
</fx:define>
```

and bind it to something

```xml
<Label text="${myString}" />
```

and of course you can inject it into the controller just like any other value:

```
public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private StringProperty myString ;

    public StringProperty myStringProperty() {
        return myString ;
    }

    public final String getMyString() {
        return myStringProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setMyString(String myString) {
        myStringProperty().set(myString);
    }

    // ...
}
```